How to detect if Youtube ad is currently playing with JavaScript
In JavaScript I need to detect if YouTube ad is currently playing, my code is not working for me. This is a single page personal project no need to use YouTube Data API.
   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      if (document.querySelector(".video-ads .ad-container, .ytp-ad-player-overlay")) {
        YouTubeAdChannel.postMessage('ad_playing');
      }
    }
  }


How would you be allowed to look in the iFrame that has the video and why would an embedded ad be detectable

Screenshot of dev console while ad is running.

you can check if class = "video-ads ytp-ad-module" is present.
